# Is there any way to restrict an application during the installation time?

Tags: android

You specify in the Android manifest file the minimum and maximum SDK version, so can you restrict the installation of an Android application depending on the processor it has eg Qualcomm or MediaTek?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element. You can also just compile for a specific CPU architecture.

Comment: can i restrict my application to install on only those devices which have qualcomm processor

Comment: may I ask why you want to restrict to only 1 CPU?

Comment: No the requirement is that i want that application should install only on those devices which have qualcom processor

Comment: I'm curious why because there might be easier ways to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: that's the project requirement not my decision.

Answer (score 0):

> so can we restrict the installation of an android application depending on the processor it has like qualcom,mediatek etc.

No, sorry. If your app takes advantage of CPU-specific capabilities, your app needs to gracefully degrade on other CPUs.